# Какое сообщение приходит при переходе окна на задний план

Tags: c++, winapi

Задача, нужно сворачивать окно, если оно ушло на задний план.
Думал отловить сообщение перехода на задний план, и в нем сворачивать, но чет не нашел такого сообщения.
Может есть какие то другие варианты?
Спасибо.

Comment: Может быть вам подойдет это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424606/lost-focus-and-gotfocus-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом случае приходит сообщение `WM_ACTIVATE`, при этом в параметрах будет выставлен флажок `WA_INACTIVE == LOWORD(wparam)`.